# how to display only the content instead of entire HTML code in TAL Portlet

Tags: plone, zope

I created new TAL portlet using collective.portlet.tal tar file and included in the packages.cfg file under [main] section.After starting instance I then installed the newly created TAL portlet in Zmi using portal_quickinstaller. USing TAL portlet(from @@manage-portlets ADD portlet dropdown menu) i added one address portlet to display my address dynamically. I then used this code in TAL Code

```
 <div tal:define="address_view context/@@address-view" >
  <span tal:replace="address_view/myaddress" />
</div>
```

it directly fetches the method and its return value from file system. The output of the above process is i m getting a entire html code in the newly address portlet. Like this i m seeing the browser

```
      <div> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8086/brunweb2  
      /brunweb//daten/spitaltaetigkeit/daten/ploneCustom.css"> <p></p> <table 
      width="180" border="0"> <tr> <td class="color" align="left" width="165" 
      valign="bottom" style="padding-top: 200px; padding-left: 30px;"> <a 
      href="http://localhost:8086/brunweb2/brunweb//daten/spitaltaetigkeit/daten/praxis
     /lageplan"><u class="TextAdresseSuchBlau">So finden Sie uns </u></a><br> <font 
     class="TextAdresseBlau">Prafhhfhxis<br> Prof. Dr. fdagdsgsdgsdgsdgdg<br>
     <br>hdfhgfhgfhgfj 30<br>3011 skm <br><br></font> <font 
     class="TextAdresseBlau">Tel:5745745745<br>Fax:574574577</font><br> <a 
     href="mailto:ssasdf.gsdgg@fgf.ch" 
     class="TextAdresseBlau">ssasdf.gsdgg@fgf.cha> </td> </tr> </table> </div>
```

But dont want to see like this in browser. I just want to show the contents in address portlet.

```
   So finden Sie uns Prafhhfhxis
   Prof. Dr. fdagdsgsdgsdgsdgdg
   hdfhgfhgfhgfj 30
   3011 skm 
   Tel: 746 4646 43
   Fax:6346 63463
   ssasdf.gsdgg@fgf.ch
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with the TAL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use structure

`<span tal:replace="structure address_view/myaddress" />`

Comment: @nirmala find TAL docs here: http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html ;)